# Regular updates on particular set of rows has degraded performance of cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In one of my tables, there are around 20 million rows(can grow more in future) which need to be updated daily.

Earlier this updation process was quite smooth (**throughput around 100K updates/min, without any increase in load avg. on machines**). But after 1 month of regular updates, performance has degraded a lot. Now, even if I try to do updates at low throughput i.e. around 30K rpm, load average on machines gets high and other queries also gets affected.

*Cassandra version*--> 2.0.14

*Machines config*--> (RAID-1, 1TB, 32core, 64 GB RAM), similar 4 machines with replication factor of 3.

*Compaction Strategy of given table* --> SizeTiered

What changes should I try to scale it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas for you:

- Cassandra prefers more small machines instead of a few large ones. It is recommended to keep heap 8GB max. large heap = long GC = pauses and lower performance (this could be your case, but you have to monitor your environment, check if it's a GC taking CPU or what). Also do not store too much data on single node, repair & compaction might take too long and take cpu.
- you could try to tune your cassandra (see e.g. [this guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html) - unfortunatelly for Cassandra 2.1)
- you may consider also cassandra upgrade
- if you update whole table daily - then this might be an anti-pattern for cassandra - large number of updates = longer compactions. if you want to keeps current design I would recommend too have more nodes with less data per node and check how much time&resources takes the compaction process

Comment: Heap size I have kept 8GB only. I will try to add more nodes and monitor. Any suggestions for small machines config?

Comment: Also I checked cassandra system logs for GC timing, there I found GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep is taking 8 sec. on an average. But its once in a day.
That might not be a issue I think.